# With format='multipart' in test client, data of nested dict been ignored or removed

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I have a nested serializer containing, containing an Image Field in the nested serializer, the serializers are:-

```py
class FloorPlanLocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = FloorPlan
        fields = (
            'floor',
            'image',
        )
        extra_kwargs = {'floor': {'required': False}, 'image': {'required': False}}


class LocationSerializer(FilterSerializerByOrgManaged, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    floorplan = FloorPlanLocationSerializer(required=False, allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = (
            'id',
            'organization',
            'name',
            'type',
            'is_mobile',
            'address',
            'geometry',
            'created',
            'modified',
            'floorplan',
        )
        read_only_fields = ('created', 'modified')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        request = self.context['request']
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        floorplans = instance.floorplan_set.all().order_by('-modified')
        floorplan_list = []
        for floorplan in floorplans:
            dict_ = {
                'floor': floorplan.floor,
                'image': request.build_absolute_uri(floorplan.image.url),
            }
            floorplan_list.append(dict_)
        data['floorplan'] = floorplan_list
        return data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        floorplan_data = None

        if validated_data.get('floorplan'):
            floorplan_data = validated_data.pop('floorplan')

        instance = self.instance or self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        with transaction.atomic():
            instance.full_clean()
            instance.save()

        if floorplan_data:
            floorplan_data['location'] = instance
            floorplan_data['organization'] = instance.organization
            with transaction.atomic():
                fl = FloorPlan.objects.create(**floorplan_data)
                fl.full_clean()
                fl.save()

        return instance
```

With this above serialzier, it works fine with DRF Browsable page, but when I try to send the data with the test client in multipart format, the nested data gets removed while send the POST request, this is how I wrote the tests:-

```
    def test_create_location_with_floorplan_api(self):
        path = reverse('geo_api:list_location')
        coords = json.loads(Point(2, 23).geojson)
        image = Image.new("RGB", (100, 100))
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".png", mode="w+b") as tmp_file:
            image.save(tmp_file, format="png")
            tmp_file.seek(0)
            byio = BytesIO(tmp_file.read())
            inm_file = InMemoryUploadedFile(
                file=byio,
                field_name="avatar",
                name="testImage.png",
                content_type="image/png",
                size=byio.getbuffer().nbytes,
                charset=None,
            )

        data = {
            'organization': self._get_org().pk,
            'name': 'test-location',
            'type': 'indoor',
            'is_mobile': False,
            'address': 'Via del Corso, Roma, Italia',
            'geometry': {'Type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [12.32,43.222]},
            'floorplan': {
                'floor': 12,
                'image': inm_file
            },
        }
        with self.assertNumQueries(6):
            response = self.client.post(path, data, format='multipart')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
```

The data doesn't come in the same format as I sent, i.e., when I try to see the data in the to_internal method this  is how I receive it:-

```
<QueryDict: {'organization': ['f6c406e5-0602-44a7-9160-ec109ac29f4c'], 'name': ['test-location'], 'type': ['indoor'], 'is_mobile': ['False'], 'address': ['Via del Corso, Roma, Italia'], 'geometry': ['type', 'coordinates'], 'floorplan': ['floor', 'image']}>
```

the values of `type`, `coordinates`, `floorplan` are not present inside it.

How can I write a proper tests for the above case???

Comment: It is helpful to create a **short** and **clear** example of the issue, rather than a code dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to post form data, you need to flatten everything the same way a browser would.  Maybe this gist will help, [flatten_dict_for_form_data](https://gist.github.com/awbacker/ed0b29df769ccd0f886a).  Its quite old and could use some cleanup, but it still works.

This recursively flattens a dict, which you can then send to test client (or to live services):

```
def flatten_dict_for_formdata(input_dict, sep="[{i}]"):
    def __flatten(value, prefix, result_dict, previous=None):
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            if previous == "dict":
                prefix += "."
                
            for key, v in value.items():
                __flatten(v, prefix + key, result_dict, "dict")

        elif isinstance(value, (list, tuple)):
            for i, v in enumerate(value):
                __flatten(v, prefix + sep.format(i=i), result_dict)
        else:
            result_dict[prefix] = value

        return result_dict

    return __flatten(input_dict, '', {})

>>> flatten_dict_for_formdata({
>>>     "name": "Test",
>>>     "location": {"lat": 1, "lng": 2},
>>>     "sizes": ["S", "M", "XL"]
>>> })

>>> {
>>>    "name": "Test",
>>>    "location.lat": 1,
>>>    "location.lng": 2,
>>>    "sizes[0]": "S",
>>>    "sizes[1]": "M",
>>>    "sizes[2]": "XL"
>>> }
```